# IF statement inside ORACLE FUNCTION

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question regarding comparing two tables, update its value and increment the rev no value.

So first of all my table structure is like this

Master Drawing table,
HEAD_MARK WEIGHT SURFACE

Dummy Master Drawing Table,
HEAD_MARK_DUM WEIGHT_DUM SURFACE DUM

and i have a function to sync the values from dummy_master_drawing to master_drawing

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION WELTESADMIN.DUM_MST_SYNC(PROJNAME IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN NUMBER IS NUM_ROWS NUMBER;
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  BEGIN
    MERGE INTO MASTER_DRAWING DST USING
    (SELECT WEIGHT_DUM, SURFACE_DUM, HEAD_MARK_DUM, PROJECT_NAME_DUM FROM DUMMY_MASTER_DRAWING) SRC 
        ON (DST.HEAD_MARK = SRC.HEAD_MARK_DUM)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET DST.WEIGHT  = SRC.WEIGHT_DUM,
               DST.SURFACE = SRC.SURFACE_DUM
    WHERE DST.PROJECT_NAME = SRC.PROJECT_NAME_DUM
    AND DST.PROJECT_NAME   = PROJNAME;
    NUM_ROWS              := SQL%ROWCOUNT;

    COMMIT;
    RETURN NUM_ROWS;
  END;
```

and i have second SQL to compare different data values,

```
Select A.HEAD_MARK, A.WEIGHT MDWEIGHT, B.WEIGHT_DUM DUMWEIGHT, 
       A.SURFACE SURFACE, B.SURFACE_DUM 
From MASTER_DRAWING A, DUMMY_MASTER_DRAWING B
    Where A.HEAD_MARK = B.HEAD_MARK_DUM AND A.WEIGHT != B.WEIGHT_DUM AND A.SURFACE != B.SURFACE_DUM
    AND A.PROJECT_NAME = B.PROJECT_NAME_DUM AND A.PROJECT_NAME = PROJNAME
```

The problem is i dont know how to integrate those 2 queries into single function. Is it better using IF Statement inside WELTESADMIN.DUM_MST_SYNC function or put the second one in a function and put those two functions inside a procedure?

or make them each a procedure and execute them two inside a function?

Please help me,
I just starting to learn oracle and i wanna be good in this stuff.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The second query looks like it is a subset (same conditions and then a few more) of the set of conditions in the merge statement (you could verify by using the minus set operator and compare a variation of similar query blocks).

Comment: By the way, are you identifying the primary key of each table?

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not put the second SQL inside a function or procedure. Do not use PL/SQL for such plain tasks. SQL will always be faster since PL/SQL has an overhead of context switching.

Having said that, your second query can be a part of the `MERGE` statement itself. It is just a `WHEN NOT MATCHED` condition. What do you want to do with unmatched rows? I believe, this question is an extension of your yesterday's question.

On high level, your requirement is :

1. Find the matching set of data between source and destination tables, and update the destination table.
2. Find the unmatched set of data between the two tables, and you need to do something about it. You may want to `insert` or `delete` those rows from destination table. Which is nothing but adding an insert/delete in the same merge statement.

Comment: On the other words I must have 3 conditions,
1. if item NOT EXISTS in DUMMY and EXISTS in MASTER then I need to set the item with 'INACTIVE' status in DWG_STATUS Column in MASTER
2. Vice Versa, I need to add into MASTER table the item from the DUMMY that is not exists in master.
3. For every record that matches, I need to adjust the value with dummy and increment the REV_NO in MASTER table.

My case is kinda complicated. I just dont know how to approach this effectively

Comment: All those steps can be done with individual SQLs. However, if you really want to use `PL/SQL` to do some more operation like error logging etc. Then do the entire process in `BULK` rather than `row-by-row` aka `slow-by-slow`. Can you provide the create table statements and insert statements.

Comment: Thanks lalit, this is the create stmt for MASTER_DRAWING
CREATE TABLE WELTESADMIN.MASTER_DRAWING
(
  HEAD_MARK           VARCHAR2(20 CHAR),
  ENTRY_DATE          DATE,
  COMP_TYPE           VARCHAR2(20 CHAR),
  WEIGHT              NUMBER(11,2),
  SURFACE             NUMBER(15,3),
  PROFILE             VARCHAR2(20 CHAR),
  PROJECT_NAME        VARCHAR2(20 CHAR),
  LENGTH              NUMBER(15,2)              NOT NULL,
  TOTAL_QTY           NUMBER(38),
  SUBCONT_STATUS      VARCHAR2(20 CHAR),
  DISTRIBUTION_COUNT  NUMBER,
  DWG_STATUS          VARCHAR2(8 CHAR)
)

Comment: And for the dummty is just another copy of master_drawing that I intended to sync between new data and old data. all the column names are added by _DUM. i.e HEAD_MARK and HEAD_MARK_DUM. I import the new data from .CSV and sync it into the old data in master_drawing